# Screen brightness keeps switching to auto & timeout to 500min

Tags: screen, screen-brightness

My Samsung Galaxy Tab 2 7" (Android v4.1.1) has been having a bizarre problem since I installed (and uninstalled) Aldiko reader.  It has been setting the Screen Timeout to 500min (which isn't even an available setting in the Display options) and the brightness to "Auto".  Regardless of any changes I make, it changes back immediately to those settings - I can actually watch it happen.

Little help?

Comment: Maybe it can be "switched off/back" by Aldiko itself? Try re-installing, disabling that feature, uninstall again? If not, contact the Aldiko devs might be worth a try: they broke it, so they should fix it ;)

Comment: No such luck, unfortunately - I've tried any number of combination of things. I'll see what the devs have to say, but they may quite possibly think it not worth the effort :P

Comment: Understandable, as you want to move away from their product. So you should place a subtle hint that users might find that app "dangerous", as it irrevertible modifies system settings, and thus might refrain from installing it in the first place ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While I wasn't able to directly address the issue, I found an app called [Screen Control](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.humayoun.screencontrolsfree) that can modify screen timeout and brightness settings for *all* applications... using this to reset things and then uninstalling it seems to have done the trick.